# Is it legal that the index for !$omp atomic different from its host's loop index variable?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I came across a question when I was learning about how to avoid a data conflict with multiple threads potential reading and writing using the OpenMP directive !$atomic.

Shown in the text below is the code snippet made up for my question. I am wondering if it is legal in FORTRAN to use a different index (here is **j**) for !$atomic than the loop index variable **i**, which is the one immediately following the directive !$omp parallel do private(a,b) ? Thanks.

```
    program main
    ...
    integer :: i,j
    integer, dimension(10000) :: vx,vy,va,vb
    ...
    va=0
!$omp parallel do private(j)
    do i=1,10000
        j=merge(vx(i),vy(i),mod(i,2)==1)
!$omp atomic update
        va(j)=va(j)+vb(j)   
    end do
!$omp end parallel do
    ...
    end program
```

Furthermore, is it OK to loop on an atomic directive?

```
    program main
    ...
    integer :: i,j
    integer, dimension(10000) :: vx,vy
    integer, dimension(12,10000) :: va,vb
    ...
    va=0
!$omp parallel do private(j,k)
    do i=1,10000
        j=merge(vx(i),vy(i),mod(i,2)==1)
        do k=1,12
!$omp atomic update
        va(k,j)=va(k,j)+vb(k,j) 
        enddo
    end do
!$omp end parallel do
    ...
    end program
```

Comment: Shouldn't `j` be private too?

Comment: Yes, I just noticed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, why not? It is just update of a memory address, there is no difference. There even wouldn't be much sense in using atomic with i in your case, as different threads have different values of `i`.

BUT, be aware of your race condition with `j` you are writing to it from more thread, it should be `private`.

Your second example adds nothing new, it is the same situation, still legal.